# What is the name of this metal bar with holes at the ends?

Tags: hardware, terminology

I need to find a metal part that looks a bit like this:

```
     hole for bolt                strong metal
      |                            |
   ___|____________________________v_______
  /   v                                    \
 (   (_)                              (_)   ) <--round end
  \________________________________________/
```

This looks like a common part from a Meccano set, but with just two holes at either end for bolts. Two of these can go around a 2x4, then bolts run through the holes.

```
    /__\                             /__\<--end of bolt
 ____________________________________________<--the part
     __                               __
     __                               __
     __                               __
     __                               __ <---bolt
     __                               __
     __                               __
     __                               __
 ____________________________________________<--the part
    [==]                             [==]<---nut
```

I am searching for a name so that I can find these to buy. Is there a common application where these appear? Are they commonly used by a particular contractor for a particular type of job? What is the name of this kind of part?

Comment: *Perforated steel strapping?* This is often sold in longer lengths with multiple holes and can be cut to length and ends rounded.

Comment: @bib I don't think that will work, as it looks flexible. I need this to be very strong.

Comment: Are you reinforcing a joint or clamping something else to timber?

Comment: 'Brace' is the common layman term.  ['Strap' or  'Tie' or 'Strap Tie'](http://www.fastenersplus.com/fasteners/Straps-Ties) is more formal.

Comment: That is some very impressive and pretty ASCII art.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(so far, other answers don't show something I'd use on a 2x4, hence this answer)

> **Two of these can go around a 2x4, then bolts run through the holes ... Is there a common application where these appear?**

"Straight Timber Connector" - for non-structural connections such as landscaping.

[image]

Smaller versions are usually called mending plates in my part of the world.

---

For structural applications involving vertical shear loads - like splicing joists - in buildings, you'd typically use something very different to that illustrated above. E.g. a "splice plate" or "nail plate".

[image]

---

As Isherwood noted, there are likely to be a variety of names for these types of connector.

Comment: +1 for showing the thing the OP needs. But IMO, the top image is a [(strap) tie](https://www.google.com/search?q=strap+tie&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisw7uuyKzVAhWQ8oMKHVCdCUkQ_AUICygC&biw=1024&bih=639), and the bottom one is a [(nail) plate](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1024&bih=639&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=nail+plates&oq=nail+plates&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.328797.329419.0.330429.4.4.0.0.0.0.473.473.4-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.1.471.tZWdypqIV7E).

Comment: If this is part of a drive chain (think motorcycle, etc), it's a *link plate*: *plate*, again!

Answer (score 14):

In the USA, this has been known as a mending plate for as long as I can recall. I might have learned about the terminology in shop class, it's that old:

[image: mending plate]

A quick google search using those terms results in far too many links to list. Stainless steel, brass, zinc plated steel, probably even copper, although the latter would be a terminal jumper rather than a mending plate. Prices from under a dollar to triple that or more.

Comment: "I might have learned about the terminology in shop class, it's that old" - FWIW that's the term I learned in shop class... 8 years ago :p

Comment: more than 40 for me! It's good to see some good stuff is still being taught.

Comment: "mending plate" is also a common name in the UK, e.g. [here](https://www.toolstation.com/shop/Construction+Materials/d210/Builders+Metalwork/sd2797/Mending+Plate/p30606).

Answer (score 6):

It's not going to have a standard name. It performs different roles in different applications, where it receives semantic names. It's just a bar or strap that's bored for fasteners.

For example, here it's a [bracelet blank](https://it.pinterest.com/pin/77405687323064605/):

[image]

And here it's a [separator bar](https://www.etsystudio.com/listing/480166100/13-hole-separator-bar-gold-plated-flat):

[image]

Comment: You forgot Erector sets :P

Answer (score 3):

I have seen these in the big box stores the are for generic timber frame connections, this is a [small sample](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Perma-Dock-System-Hardware-Washer-Plate-HLW/100431484), not exactly what I seen but gets the idea across. It is 5"X 1/12", the square holes will not matter. They are a help if you use carriage bolts

Answer (score 1):

It is Available in Hardware store and it called **Coupling Plates** available in many length or you can make by yourself just by drilling holes on plates but if you want strong steel plates purchase pre holed plates.

Answer (score 0):

FISHPLATES or COUPLERS is quite a common term in the UK

Answer (score 0):

If it's for electrical it's a bus bar plate.

Answer (score 0):

### That is the mount(ing) plate for a U-bolt,

like this:

[image: u-bolt with mount plate]

Answer (score -2):

BRACKET OR IT'S ROOT - BRACE, BRACING.